# Start a activity like a "Dialog", by writing java code

Tags: android, themes, android-theme

I want to make a activity like a "Dialog", and I know two ways so far:

**Way 1)** In Android ApiDemos, it is implemented by adding the attribute to the activity like

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

The result is: the new Activity appears on top of the existing activity, that is what I want.

**Way 2)** I try to invoke `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog)` in the `Activity.onCreate(Bundle)` method, and the new activity also appears, but the background is all black.  This is not what I want. Code is as below:

```
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.selecte_date);
```

Can anybody tell me how to implement the effect by writing Java code?

Comment: way 1 is thru xml decleration way 2 is java progrmatically setting.

Comment: Thanks.  I know what you mean. Actually I want to know how to make a new activity appears on top of an existing activity, by writing java code, not by writing xml.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a second layout in you xml which is a overlay of existing one.
then you can set the overlay to visible in your activity. So then you got multiple views in 1 activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"  >
<LinearLayout

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/translucent_black"
    android:visibility="false" >
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So do you mean `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);` can not make an activity like a dialog?

Comment: What I mean is that you create an extra view what overlays the existing one. The new view has a semi-transparent background just like a dialog. in the code set the view overlay visibility to VISIBLE and you got a custom dialog in your existing activity

Comment: Thanks.I understand what you mean. But I actually want start an activity, rather than make a view from INVISIBLE to VISIBLE. Because if I start an activity, the area outside the activity can not be clicked, however, if I use another view, the area outside the view can be clicked. So using another view is more like a PopupWindow, not a Dialog.

Comment: If you set the view size to fill parent, then you can only click on the new view and not outside the view. If you try my code sample, then you could test it.